# Bug in Bootstrap 5 Navbar

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a simple web-dev project. I'm using bootstrap 5 and I'm struggling to create the navbar. The code for the navbar is in header.html.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <img src="/Users/morgan/Documents/12_london_app_brewery/london_app_brew/88-cafe-wifi/img/free_wifi.png" alt="Free Wifi" style="width:40px;" class="rounded-pill">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('home') }}">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('add_cafe') }}">Add</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I have `{% include "header.html" %}` in my index.html and add.html files.

The navbar looks like the following

[image]

Note that the photo is not displaying and "Home" and "Add" are not aligned to the right.

Answer (score 0):

Check your bundle of Bootstrap file.

If you have your **custom.scss** (or any other name), where you importing Bootstrap’s source Sass files, check if missed navbar imports:

```css
...
@import "~bootstrap/scss/nav";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/navbar";
...
```

To move **navbar-nav** to right side, use "ms-auto" instead of "mr-auto" (BS 5.1);

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">



<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <img src="/Users/morgan/Documents/12_london_app_brewery/london_app_brew/88-cafe-wifi/img/free_wifi.png" alt="Free Wifi" style="width:40px;" class="rounded-pill">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
      <!-- to move navbar-nav use "ms-auto" -->
      <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('home') }}">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('add_cafe') }}">Add</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

---

I see you have artifact text on the left "**-->**". May be you just have issues with open/closing tags or comments and because of that your DOM is broken.

[image]